# Read csv to dict of lists of dicts

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a data set with tons of (intentional) duplication. I'd like to collapse(?) that to make it better suited for my needs. The data reads like this:

```
Header1, Header2,  Header3
Example1, Content1, Stuff1
Example1, Content2, Stuff2
Example1, Content3, Stuff3
Example2, Content1, Stuff1
Example2, Content5, Stuff5
etc...
```

And I want that to end up as a dict with column one's values as keys and lists of dicts as values to those keys like so:

```
{Example1 : [{Header2:Content1, Header3:Stuff1}, {Header2:Content2, Header3:Stuff2}, {Header2:Content3, Header3:Stuff3}],
 Example2 : [{Header2:Content1, Header3:Stuff1}, {Header2:Content5, Header3:Stuff5}]}
```

I'm brand new to Python and a novice programmer over all so feel free to get clarification if this question is confusing.  Thanks!

**Update** I was rightfully called out for not posting my example code (thanks for keeping me honest!) so here it is. The code below *works* but since I'm new to Python I don't know if it's well written or not. Also the dict ends up with the keys (Example1 and Example2) in reverse order. That doesn't really matter but I do not understand why.

```
def gather_csv_info():
    all_csv_data = []
    flattened_data = {}
    reading_csv = csv.DictReader(open(sys.argv[1], 'rb'))

    for row in reading_csv:
        all_csv_data.append(row)

    for row in all_csv_data:
        if row["course_sis_ids"] in flattened_data:
            flattened_data[row["course_sis_ids"]].append({"user_sis_ids":row["user_sis_ids"], "file_ids":row["file_ids"]})
        else:
            flattened_data[row["course_sis_ids"]] = [{"user_sis_ids":row["user_sis_ids"], "file_ids":row["file_ids"]}]

    return flattened_data
```

Comment: I dont see no code. What did you try and why does it not work?

Comment: your question is way too broad specially without any code to show the context.

Comment: I haven't posted in a long time and completely forgot my etiquette. Thanks @MikeScotty for that site, it's awesome.

Comment: @lyonsinbeta You're welcome. I have removed my downvote. Cheers =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code works but I don't know how pythonic it is and I don't understand why the `flattened_data` dict has the keys in reverse order that they appear in the original CSV. It doesn't strictly matter that they're not in order, but it is curious.

```
def gather_csv_info():
    all_csv_data = []
    flattened_data = {}
    reading_csv = csv.DictReader(open(sys.argv[1], 'rb'))

    for row in reading_csv:
        all_csv_data.append(row)

    for row in all_csv_data:
        if row["course_sis_ids"] in flattened_data:
            flattened_data[row["course_sis_ids"]].append({"user_sis_ids":row["user_sis_ids"], "file_ids":row["file_ids"]})
        else:
            flattened_data[row["course_sis_ids"]] = [{"user_sis_ids":row["user_sis_ids"], "file_ids":row["file_ids"]}]

    return flattened_data
```

Comment: Dictionaries do not preserve keys in order, that's not what dictionaries are for. If you need the order, use a list or OrderedDict instead.

Comment: I don't need them in order, I know the point of key:value pairs is that they don't need to be in a known order, I was just commenting that I don't know why they're in the order they're in since it's not the order they were read into the dict.

Comment: You can create an `OrderedDict` that does preserve insertion order.

Answer (score -1):

I completely changed the answer as you changed your question, so instead I just tidied the code in your own answer so it's more "Pythonic":

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def gather_csv_info(filename):
    all_csv_data = []
    flattened_data = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            key = row["Header1"]
            flattened_data[key].append({"Header2":row["Header2"], "Header3":row["Header3"]})
    return flattened_data

print(gather_csv_info('data.csv'))
```

Not sure why you want the data in this format, but that's up to you.

Comment: Downvoting without a comment is not helpful, as people still learning will have to make a guess as to why it's bad, and probably get it wrong.

Comment: The file is a CSV, I just made a simple table for readability sake. I updated it with commas but left the spaces to maintain readability.

Comment: Not very helpful. If you post a question, people will spend time trying to provide you with a solution based on what you posted. If you edit the question to be completely different, those answers get unfairly downvoted. And you've also gone and accepted your own answer, which has far from exemplary code, and that is not very helpful for the next programmer either...

Comment: I'll happily change the selected answer if someone provides a better one, or if I come up with a better one, but the answer I provided does address the question. At least if someone finds this question they'll see a working solution, with the note that it's a novice's attempt.

Comment: I edited my question to show an improved version of your code. If you want you can even copy that into your question.